# Python List to save in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, list, pymongo

I have an excel sheet of data. I made each rows as an dictionary and then appended them in a Python list. I am trying to save my Recipes list into the cluster but it shows error.

```python
import sys

import pymongo
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Final Recipe Dataset.xlsx')

ws = wb.active

temparray = []
for row in range(0, ws.max_row):
    values = []
    for col in ws.iter_cols(1, ws.max_column):
        values.append(col[row].value)
    temparray.append(values)
#321
#168
Recipes = []

for i in range(1, 321):
    rrecipe = {}
    for j in range(0, 168):
        if temparray[i][j] == 0: continue
        rrecipe[temparray[0][j]] = temparray[i][j]
    Recipes.append(rrecipe)

print(sys.getsizeof(Recipes))

uri = "mongodb+srv://tanviropy:<password>@cluster0.lftvw.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://tanviropy:<password>@cluster0.lftvw.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
cluster = client["xx"]
db = cluster["x"]

print(Recipes[0])

try:
    db.insert_many(Recipes)
    print("MongoDB Connected")
except:
      print('Error occurred')
```

I have an excel sheet of data. I made each rows as an dictionary and then appended them in a Python list. I am trying to save my Recipes list into the cluster but it shows error. Can anyone tell me how can I solve the problem?

I am getting following error msg:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError:
cluster0-shard-00-01.lftvw.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992),
cluster0-shard-00-00.lftvw.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992),
cluster0-shard-00-02.lftvw.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992),
Timeout: 30s,
Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 64fc4f144b2ef5097b04ae99,
topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary,
servers: [
<ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-00.lftvw.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None,
  error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-00.lftvw.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)')>,
<ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-01.lftvw.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None,
  error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-01.lftvw.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)')>,
<ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-02.lftvw.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None,
  error=AutoReconnect('cluster0-shard-00-02.lftvw.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)')>
]>
```

Comment: Could you please edit the question with the full error?
Without seeing the error, debugging is tough

Comment: If you install the Python package [`certifi`](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/), do you make progress?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: If you use `client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://tanviropy:<password>@cluster0.lftvw.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority", tlsCAFile=certifi.where())`, any better luck?